# Calculating the day of month by adding x days to current date

Tags: php, algorithm

I'm looking for a more "low-level" solution to this problem. I know there are good functions in PHP for this, but I'm searching for a more general algorithm (to improve my understanding).

Suppose that a holiday is exactly 69 days from a date. The function prototype could look like this:

```
function calculate_holiday($month, $day) { }
```

The month and day could be anything, for an example, suppose $month = 4, $day = 15

**My solution:**
Since the total number of days in some months are different, this needs to be taken into account, so let's say we have a function get_month_days($month) that returns the number of days for that month. So I was thinking:

```
function calculate_holiday($month, $day)
{
    $in_days = 69;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $in_days; $i++)
    {
        if (get_month_days($month) == $i)
        {
            // reached total number of days in that month, set day to 1 and add 1 
            // to $month variable
            $day = 1;
            $month += 1;
        } else {
            $day += 1;
        }
    }
    return array('month' => $month, 'day' => $day);
}
```

This works perfectly, but I think there's a much more simpler version. It feels like setting  day to 1 and add 1 to month just seems a bit messy. I'd really appreciate some help on this if someone sees a more better way..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. What is the `calculate_holiday()` function supposed to do?

Comment: Let's just suppose that we have a holiday that is dependent on a date that you can choose freely, in this case 69 days after that date. If the chosen date is the month 4 (April) and day 15, then the holiday will happen 69 days from that date.

Comment: You still haven't answered my question "What is the function supposed to do?" Are you trying to simply add X days to a given date and get the month name and day of the resulting date? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DateTime https://www.php.net/manual/pl/class.datetime.php,
It should be a standard for working with dates in PHP nowadays.

```
function calculate_holiday($year, $month, $day, $in_days = 69;) {
  $date = new \DateTime();
  $date->setDate($year, $month, $day);
  $date->modify('+'.$in_days.' days');
  return array('month' => $date->format('m'), 'day' => $date->format('d'));
}

print_r(calculate_holiday('2014', '02', '15'));
```

Comment: Thanks mate. However, I'm aware of that PHP has some nice libraries for this task, but I want to try and do this on a lower level.

Comment: Why? It is built in in PHP, do you need to solve this problem on algorithmical level, as it is some kind of homework? :D

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but even when there are good libraries out there, it doesn't mean that you shouldn't understand or know how to implement things yourself. =)

Comment: Although, I think I'll get some better ideas to just dive into the PHP's repository on Github instead. I'll mark your answer as the right. :)